# Display filter on all products category like the other category pages in opencart 2.3

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

I have a opencart 2.3 store and I have downloaded a extension that shows all products on one page, it creates a category called All and displays all products in that category.

It's working all ok but I would like to have the product filter displayed in the left column so it's the same as the other categories.

For example the category here https://www.beechwoodsolutions.co.uk/sites/simply-heavenly-foods/index.php?route=product/category&path=271 has the product filter in the left column.

On the all products category page here https://www.beechwoodsolutions.co.uk/sites/simply-heavenly-foods/index.php?route=product/category&path=-1 I would like to have the product filter displayed.

The extension I downloaded is https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=29713.

I have contacted the developer but don't think they are active anymore so was seeing if anyone was able to help please.

I think it might be to do with the following section of code but not 100% sure

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($result['category_id']==-1)
            continue;

        //foreach ($results as $result) {
            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_category_id'  => $result['category_id'],
                'filter_sub_category' => true
            );

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name' => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
            );
        }
```